# Why Installshield LE Visual Studio 2010 Primary Output puts generated files on desktop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010, with seven projects. I have added a Installshield LE Setup project and when I add my main projects Primary-Output and then add a shortcut for the Primary-Output on the desktop, in the Installshield assistant.

Now when I install my application it creates a shortcut on the desktop, as expected. But when I run my application; it has a built-in logging class that generates a few log files. Now when I click the shortcut on the desktop to run the application, it creates my log files on the desktop, as well as where they are supposed to be created, which is the applications directory.

Why does installshield do this, because it's my understanding that it should only link to the .exe in the applications install folder, not think that it's launching the application from it's install folder.

I have gotten this to work by manually adding my output files to the setup project, but this is not ideal, as I would love to be able to configure this and then when I need to build a new installer, just build project and it's done.

If anybody can recommend a better installer that fits my needs, that would be great.

**Installer Requirements**

- shortcut on desktop for application
- shortcut on desktop for a url shortcut
- shortcut in startup folder for application
- eula

Something that is simple to get a setup project created, as I have a deadline and was only given 1 day to build and package a release build for a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your app is creating log files wherever it's launched from, which isn't really Installshield's fault. You should really be writing to somewhere like the LocalApplicationData folder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx